# Include layout is not displaying in the eclipse layout editor in android

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

The viewGroup (INCLUDE somelayout)(/INCLUDE) is not displaying in the eclipse graphical layout editor.What is the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that works for me is to leave the project open in the workspace, close Eclipse and reopen it... and **Shazaaaaam**... it should work.

:)

Comment: Worked for me. Just wish there was a cleaner fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys.But i found an another solution  start the eclipse with -clean command on the command prompt.(eclipse -clean)this  fixed the layout displaying  problem.

Comment: I use it by default, in my eclipse.lnk file, and it still gives an error sometimes when there is an include layout contained in another layout xml.